Is a const view of a variable well-defined?
If you have a variable that is actually constant after it has been set in initialization code, is it okay to have it declared const in the header file? For instance:
extdef.h:
#ifndef DEFINING_X
extern const int x;
#endif

void init_x();

extdef.c:
#define DEFINING_X

#include "xdef.h"

int x;

void init_x() { x = 42; }

main.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "xdef.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    init_x();
    printf("x is %d\n", x);
}

Obviously this isn’t completely safe, since it relies on init_x to be called before x is accessed, but if I guarantee that, can I trust that this is well-defined? It appears to work in the expected way when I test it.
Note that I’m only using plain C, not C++.

Summary of the duplicate: it causes undefined behavior, and therefore not valid.


Is a const view of a variable well-defined?

No.

f you have a variable that is actually constant after it has been set in initialization code, is it okay to have it declared const in the header file?

No.

can I trust that this is well-defined?

No.
From https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.7p2 :

All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Both extern const int x; and int x; refer to the same object.
From https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.7p1 :

Two types have compatible type if their types are the same. Additional rules for determining whether two types are compatible are described [...] in 6.7.3 for type qualifiers [...]

From https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p10 :

For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version of a compatible type [...]

The type const int x and int x are not compatible, because are differently qualified. The rules are broken, the code has undefined behavior. You can read about undefined behavior at Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior .
This is also mentioned in the https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2 :

The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:

Two declarations of the same object or function specify types that are not compatible



I think it's right, it is possible to declare a variable as const in the header file if it is actually a constant after being set in the initialization code. Your code is quite correct.
You can test it:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "xdef.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("x is %d before calling init_x()\n", x);
    init_x();
    printf("x is %d after calling init_x()\n", x);
    return 0;
}

Output:
x is 0 before calling init_x()
x is 42 after calling init_x()


Thanks, but your answer doesn’t really contribute any new information. I need to know whether it’s well-defined, for instance that the value of x is not pre-fetched before or during the call to init_x as an optimization.

The OP's code is not correct, even if you find an implementation that accepts it (which I can entirely believe you might).  "It happens to work in implementation X", or even "... in most implementations" is not at all the same thing as "it has well defined behavior".  See the dupe target and / or the other answer.

Also, "I didn't observe any failures" is not the same thing as "it will always work".  If you watch a busy highway for 20 seconds and don't see any wrecks happen, you can't conclude no one will ever get killed in a car accident - yet that is exactly the same logic you've applied here.
